# Dismis showDetailViewController swift

Tags: swift, ios8, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am using the showDetailViewController to show a webview, but i am having problems to close it.

how can i close it?

this is how i am calling it

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var link = (feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("link") as String)
    link = trataLink(link)

    let navegador = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idNavegadorViewController") as NavegadorViewController

    navegador.linkURL = NSURL(string: link)

    showDetailViewController(navegador, sender: self)

}
```

Best regards you all!

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close it pretty easy by using `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the `UIViewController` you want to dismiss:

```
navegador.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Maybe you need to make the `NavegadorViewController` a global variable, so that you can access it from another method.

Comment: added an IBAction func with the dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil), worked perfectly!  really thank you